# Unknown status icon in Android

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

[image: What is the most right icon right to the clock alarm icon ?]

I saw this most to the right icon just few days ago and I don't understand its meaning, anyone have an idea ?

Comment: It is Galaxy s7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a quick google search gave me this answer : [image]

Data saver icon

You will see this Galaxy S9 status icon if you enable data saver in Settings — Connections —Data usage — Data saver.

taken from : https://gadgetguideonline.com/s9/meaning-of-galaxy-s9-status-icons-and-notification-icons-in-samsung-galaxy-s9-and-s9/